# Remainder of an integer divided by 5 is the same as the remainder of the division of the rightmost digit by 5 how to prove this?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

we have been told in arithmetic that the remainder of an integer divided by 5 is the same as the remainder of the division of the rightmost digit by 5 
how to use modular properties to prove this?

Comment: I assume that you are working in base $10$, right? So if we have a number, let's say
$$
123456
$$
This is the same as
$$
123450+6
$$
Taking modulo $5$, we get
$$
123450+6  \equiv 0+1 \equiv 1 \mod{5}
$$
This is because the first part is always $\equiv 0 \mod{5}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a number $\overline{a_1a_2a_3a_4....a_n}$. Now this can be written as $$ a_1\times 10^{n-1} +a_2\times 10^{n-2}+.....+a_{n-1}\times 10 +a_n$$
Now when you reduce this by $5$ you will get some remainder say $r$. We have
$$ a_1\times 10^{n-1}n +a_2\times 10^{n-2}+.....+a_{n-1}\times 10 +a_n\equiv r\pmod5$$
$$\implies a_n\equiv r\pmod5$$.

Comment: I didn't understand can you explain

Comment: @ghadah32,  the number which we considered in the beginning consists of digits $a_1,.....,a_n$.

Comment: Now this number can be rewritten as in step 2. Now if you divide this by 5 then all the terms of this "sum" upto the second -last term are divisible by 5.

Comment: as $10$ is divisible by $5$,  $a_i\times10 ,\forall 1\le i\le n-1 $  is also divisible by $5$

Comment: Now you only have to see what remainder $a_n$ i.e the last digit of the number leaves when divided by 5 to find out the remainder our original number will leave when divided by 5.

Comment: Step 2 is nothing but the decimal representation of the number we considered.

Comment: got it clear thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In decimal place-value notation, $edcba = 10\times edcb + a$. More generally, if $a$ is the right-most digit of a number $n$, then $n=10\times m + a$ for an appropriate number $m$.